# ASP.NET changing the hyperlink text and url in master page from content page

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, master-pages

I have a hyperlink on my masterpage "login/register. 
I want after a user has completed the login to change this Hyperlink's text on all content pages to "log out" and change the Url. 
Also I need to change it back after like 20 min- where do a declare this?

thanx

Comment: Do you check if a user is logged in somewhere?

Comment: yes I'm just working on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property in the master page. You will get the masterpage object from the child page which you need to cast to proper type, i.e. type of your masterpage and then you will be able to access the property of the master page.

This property will give you information about the status of user and you will be able to communicate to child pages and pass data using this property.

Comment: I've done something like this, and it works. 
now I need to change the url.

    ((HyperLink)Master.FindControl("HyperLink1")).Text =        Session["UserFirstName"].ToString() +" "+   Session["UserFirstName"].ToString() +" "+ "hello";

Comment: You should set the NavigateUrl property of the hyperlink and you are done.